# Read Huge Data from CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the requirement to read/search the huge amount of data from CoreData API. Are there any library/tools/suggestions to read the data to look like real time. Does it do necessary caching itself or should I be worrying about creating my own cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general core date will automatically solve all the problems you mention. I.e., it should be responsive, has good caching policy APIs etc.

There are some great suggestions on the Apple WWDC videos, for example about strategies to optimize free text search on lots of data. Search for "core data" and you will find them on Apples developer web site (need to be registered as a developer).

That being said, remember that lacking a precise quantification of "huge data", there are real limitations on mobile devices, so you will have to make intelligent choices about how you want your data to interact with the mobile UI.